# How to use Full FOV videos on raspberry pi v2 camera? python

Tags: python, video, raspberry-pi

I would like to take a video with the maximum amount of horizontal area in the video.
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html

The documents show that they have 7 modes. with several fields of view.
I was wondering If i could record with the max FOV and down sample to a 224*224 resolution. I'm fine with losing FOV in both directions to achieve the 1:1 Aspect ratio.

I have tried to use in the `picamera.Picamera(sensor_mode=5)`.
But I have not been able to get the max FOV out of this by trying different values.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but from my experience and [the docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/fov.html) the FOV is dependent upon the framerate and resolution. So if you are setting those then it will affect the FOV. It looks like the way to get the full FOV is by using modes 2 or 3.